# why does a Context reload when user leaves browser tab and returns back

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

I am using a Context to serve data across all the components of my app. I am using Next.js as the React framework. I notice that every time, the user moves to another tab of the browser and returns to the application tab, the context gets reloaded. I put a log in the `useEffect(()=> {console.log(...)}, [])` of the Context.js

The effect of this is: In my use-case, the context is to share some db data and functions. Consequently, the database re-loading unnecessarily occurs.

The app is a standard, simple one. I am leaving out the business logic since it is not important to the question. The relevant code is shown below

```
// _app.js (I am using next.js)

import Layout from 'components/Layout'
import { ThemeProvider } from "next-themes";
import { DataProvider } from 'contexts/DataContext'

...

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  const router = useRouter()

  // simplified the return
  return (
    <Layout>
      <ThemeProvider>
         <DataProvider>
           <Component {...pageProps} />
          </DataProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Layout>
  )
}
export default MyApp
```

and the context

```
# DataContext.js

import { createContext, useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react"

const DataContext = createContext()

export function DataProvider({ children}) {

  // some data
  const [list, setList] = useState([])
  const [somedata, setSomeData] = useState(null)  

  // some functions
  const loadInit = () => {
   ...
  }

  const getData = (params) => {
   ...
  }

  // other functions
  ...
  ...  

  useEffect(() => {
      // this gets called everytime user returns to tab in browser
      // causing the loadinit to be reloaded everytime the user
      // returns to the open application in the tab
      loadinit()
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={{
       list,
       somedata,
       getData,
       ....
    }}>
    {children}
    </DataContext.Provider> 
  )
}

export default DataContext
```

And this is how the Context is used in any page

```
// index.js

import DataContext from 'contexts/DataContext'
import Header from 'components/Header'
...

const Home = () => {
  ... 
  const { list, getData } = useContext(DataContext)
  ...

   return (
    .... list will be used here
   )
}

export default Home
```

Is there a way to avoid it? Currently, I am setting a state in DataContext to check whether it is a first time load or not.

Thanks.